# Como fazer uma div ocultar ao clicar fora dela com jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Olá.

Como faço para que essa div fique oculta quando clico fora dela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que ela desapareça quando clicar fora dela.

Segue um exemplo parecido:

```js
$("body").on("click", function() {
   $(".passageiros-div").slideUp("slow/400/fast");
});
```

```css
.passageiros-div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="passageiros-div">
    <p>Titulo</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Frase de Teste</h1>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Repare que quando clico dentro da  ela tambem some, precisava que ela sumisse somente quando clico fora dela.

Alguem sabe como fazer isso com jQuery?

Comment: Opa fala ai, então cara, tenta colocar o título da sua pergunta mais descritivo, tenta colocar também o código HTML para facilitar do pessoal reproduzir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de ter um auscultador de eventos no `document` e quando houver um `click` verificar se o `event.target` foi dentro do elemento que tens. Podes usar o [`.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) que verifica se um elemento contem outro.

Por exemplo assim:

```js
var divNome = document.querySelector(".div-nome");
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  var fora = !divNome.contains(e.target);
  if (fora) $(divNome).slideDown("slow/400/fast");
  console.log(fora ? 'Fora!' : 'Dentro!');
});


$(divNome).on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).slideUp("slow/400/fast");
});
```

```css
.div-nome {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-nome">Clica aqui, ou fora</div>
```

Comment: Como fazer com que a div oculte somente quando clico fora dela?

Comment: @Newtech troca o lugar de `slideDown` e `slideUp` no meu código...

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado!!

Comment: @Newtech ótimo!

Answer (score 1):

Somente clicando fora da div

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) 
{
    var container = $(".passageiros-div");

    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="passageiros-div">
<p>Paragrafo dentro da div a ser ocultada</p>
  </div>
  <div>
<h1>titulo fora da div a ser ocultada</h1>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```